# Fast way to modify a field for rows having the same values in multiple columns (in bash)?

Tags: bash

(it doesn't seem complicated, so I'm sorry if it's a duplicated question; I didn't manage to formulate it well enough for a good search!)

I have a file with five columns:

```
dog   5   red     car    10   
dog   9   blue    car    10
cat   1   blue    car    18
owl   5   red     car    15
bla   8   blue    train  100
bla   2   red     train  100
...
```

I want to find rows matching the same values in columns **1, 4 and 5** (rows (1,2) and (5,6) in the example above), and modify their value in column 2 to "0", as in:

```
dog   0   red     car    10   
dog   0   blue    car    10
cat   1   blue    car    18
owl   5   red     car    15
bla   0   blue    train  100
bla   0   red     train  100
...
```

I am doing that by looping through the unique values of column 1 and using grep + awk to find the matches and modify their values. However, I actually have a large file (> 10000 rows, 15 columns) and I would like to find a way of finding the matches without having to read the file multiple times in the loop. Any ideas for bash or a perl one-liner to speed that up?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a coding service.

Comment: You can try find new tools, though, no? Maybe someone did something similar. I'm waiting for the answer/proposition

Comment: will the 'matching' rows always be next to each other in the file (like shown in the sample)? in other words, are all lines with `dog/red/car` listed right after each other or could they be spread throughout the file?  how big (MBytes) is your biggest file?

Comment: do you need to preserve order of rows?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `awk` (And assuming columns are delimited by tabs):

```sh
$ awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t"}
       NR == FNR { dups[$1,$4,$5]++; next }
       dups[$1,$4,$5] > 1 { $2 = 0 }
       1' input.txt input.txt
dog     0       red     car     10
dog     0       blue    car     10
cat     1       blue    car     18
owl     5       red     car     15
bla     0       blue    train   100
bla     0       red     train   100
```

This does read the file twice in order to find all lines with the same three fields, but I don't think there's a good way to avoid two passes through the data one way or another while preserving order. For example, a `perl` version that only reads the file once, but stores all the contents in memory to iterate over at the end, so still two passes:

```sh
perl -F"\t" -lane '$dups->{$F[0]}{$F[3]}{$F[4]}++;
                   push @lines, [@F];
                   END {
                     for my $l (@lines) {
                       $l->[1] = 0 if $dups->{$l->[0]}{$l->[3]}{$l->[4]} > 1;
                       print join("\t", @$l);
                     }
                   }' input.txt
```